# How to list available twilio phone numbers in all countries?

Tags: rest, twilio, twilio-php

It is possible to get a list of all available twilio phone numbers in a particular country using REST API. Following code will list available numbers in US with area code 302.

```
 $numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
    "AreaCode"     => "302",
    "VoiceEnabled" => "true",
));
```

but the list should contains numbers from multiple countries. Is there any way to list available twilio phone numbers in all countries (or multiple countries like US and CA) using REST API ?.
Looping above described REST API call with every country code is a solution. But that is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

As per `Twilio` API documentation, the following method queries [this API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local):

```
$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
    "AreaCode"     => "302",
    "VoiceEnabled" => "true",
));
```

Please note that `{IsoCountryCode}` does not take array or any list as input. But what you could probably do is, get the list of country code by downloading the CSV file that has list of all ISO country codes where `Twilio` offers service
or another way is https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#countries. Either way, loop through the API method by providing country code from [CSV](https://www.twilio.com/resources/rates/international-phone-number-rates.csv) one by one in the method you posted but don't mention any area code. That way you will get a list of available phone numbers in all countries.

There is no dedicated API for querying all countries as you would want so it has to be 1 API request per country.

Comment: Anyway thanks for answering. but i am currently using this approach. I just want to know  one thing, whether there is a dedicated REST  API call available instead of looping.

Comment: There isnt any API request specifically for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no API method that will return available numbers from more than one country at a time.

There are only the [local](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local), [toll-free](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#toll-free) and [mobile](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#mobile) list resources and each requires a country code to search within. You can find all the countries that have numbers that you can search for by calling the [supported countries and types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#countries) resource.

Comment: i have checked that. So we can't confirm that there is no single way to solve this.

Comment: There is no single API request to make that returns numbers from any country, you have to use the country specific endpoints. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps I can suggest a different way you could use the API?